# Highchart Scrollbar position

Tags: highcharts

How to set scrollbar position to **Left** in highcharts/highstock ?
[image]

As shown in image when the chart loads,
The scrollbar is **automatically aligned to right**.
**Is there a way to position it to Left** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this thing using setting min to 0

```
 xAxis: {
    min: 0, //setting min to 0
    max: 5
},
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/2279/) is Jsfiddle link .

Comment: This answer and the jsFiddle appear to show how to display the full range on the chart, but not how to show the chart with the scrollbar on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setExtremes http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes() and define range for scrollbar.